# How to reset dropdown list <select> on 'back' button of browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to reset (back to 0 index) dropdown list  on 'back' button of browser using Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a dropdown (`<select>`) element to be reset to its default value when the user goes back **to** your page via the "Back" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

var orig_default = -1;

function setDefault() {
if (orig_default < 0) {orig_default = document.getElementById("MyList").selectedIndex;}
}

function testReset() {
if (orig_default >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("MyList").selectedIndex = orig_default;
 }
}
</script>
<body onbeforeunload='setDefault();'>
```

Here are couple of scripts which I have written myself to solve the issue of resetting the value of html  upon browser back button click.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the 'onbeforeunload' event:

```
<script>
function reset_options() {
    document.getElementById('MySelect').options.length = 0;
    return true;
}

</script>
<body onbeforeunload='reset_options()'>
...
```

Comment: I don't think this will address the actual problem that the original question is asking about.

Comment: Oh wait; I suppose it could! If this is on the original page and the user goes "forward" by loading other URLs into the tab, and then eventually clicks "Back" to return, then this would have left the original page with the `<select>` element reset ... however it's not clear that by "reset" the original question meant "cleared of all options".

Comment: @epascarello: This doesn't deserve a -1, the OP wasn't really clear as to what he meant when he said "reset".

Comment: This causes the selector to shrink in size when we submit the form. It's perceptible. Not usable for me unfortunately.

Comment: @Max you can force size via css so that it doesn't depend on its content

Answer (score 6):

yes its easy.

i have a dropbox and its id was "stroke_style"
the reset is just to set it at -1 index (before 0)

```
document.getElementById("stroke_style").selectedIndex = -1;
```

example: http://languagelassi.blogspot.in/search/label/Dropdown%20Reset%20Javascript

and you can put it in a method or directly `<body onload="">` of that page